# how to change parts of XML file by using textfields in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

this is the xml file that I'm using:

```
<Books>
<Book ISBN="0553212419">
<title>
Sherlock Holmes: Complete Novels and Stories, Vol 1
</title>
<author>Sir Arthur Conan Doyle</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0743273567">
<title>The Great Gatsby</title>
<author>F. Scott Fitzgerald</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0684826976">
<title>Undaunted Courage</title>
<author>Stephen E. Ambrose</author>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="0743203178">
<title>Nothing Like It In the World</title>
<author>Stephen E. Ambrose</author>
</Book>
</Books>
```

If I want the title of the first book: "Sherlock Holmes: Complete Novels and Stories, Vol 1" to become "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone". how can I do that with an text field in as3 so I fill in "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone" to change it??

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the XML simply by calling `myBooksXML.Book[selectedIndex].title = newValue` like you would with any object (in the case of your example `selectedIndex` would need to be 0. You may need get in-depth information from [Working with XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html) in the ActionScript docs because sometimes the XML object can be abit tricky.

Comment: I have put it like this: var newValue1 = verander.text;
 go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

xmlData.Book.author.text()[0] = newValue1;
}